# GC overhead limit exceeded in neo4j

Tags: caching, memory, neo4j, garbage-collection

When I was trying to create relationships in millions of flights and airports, I got this message `GC overhead limit exceeded in neo4j`. I am currently working on my standalone PC with `4GB RAM` and `Processor Intel(R) Core(TM)i3`. I thought that may be this reason is due to shortage of RAM memory.

So what advice could you give me to solve this problem?

Thanks, your cooperation is truly appreciated!

sams

Comment: What technology you are using to create those relationships?

Comment: [tag:MicTech] I am using Neo4j technology to create the graph database of flight search engine.

Comment: Are you using driver, neo4j unmanaged extension, REST API or Cypher thru web console?

Comment: [tag:Mictech] I am using cypher web console

Comment: then my answer is correct, you need to limit how many relationships will be created during one request.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to create relationships in batches as a first step.

If you are using Cypher you can limit how many relationships will be created during one request.

Comment: Thanks for the post @MicTech, how can I limit the query you mentioned?